# Recommended books/articles for learning set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, book-recommendation

What is the recommended reading for thoroughly learning set theory? I'm currently studying Kunen's book [1]. But what then, and in what order? One needs to learn large cardinals, inner models and descriptive set theory.

Is it a good idea to try to read Jech's bible [2] from front to back? (quite dense/difficult) Or read Kanamori [3] first? What about descriptive set theory? Does it make sense to study the classical theory in detail first [4], or should one start right away with Moschovakis [5]?

Literature:

[1] Set Theory, K. Kunen (2011)

[2] Set Theory, T. Jech (2003)

[3] The Higher Infinite, A. Kanamori (2008)

[4] Classical Descriptive Set Theory, A. Kechris (1995)

[5] Descriptive Set Theory, Y. N. Moschovakis (1980)

Other recommendations? What's the recommended reading for learning inner/core models and fine structure?

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/73075/6085).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is "too elementary" for your puropses, but I like very much the set-theory parto of the Topology book of Kelley

http://www.zbmath.org/?q=%28%28kelley+topology%29+ai:kelley.john-leroy%29+py:1975

Comment: This is the standard source for _Morse-Kelley_ set theory, which is stronger than ZFC.