# How can I define (generally) a set in ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In naive set theory we can consider sets like:

$$
A = \{ x\mid x\ \text{is a letter of the English alphabet} \}
$$
or
$$
B = \{ x \mid x\ \text{is a painting of Picasso} \}
$$
(Is this ↑ true?)

And maybe say that $$ \{``a",``b",``d"\} \subseteq A  $$

Can you do the same in ZFC?

If any of the two above questions is false, how can you talk about these "informal entities"?

Comment: Way is to choose some well known monograph/author in set theory and follow it.

Comment: Such as...? This isn't very helpful

Comment: Also, I asked this question because reading about zfc I'm only encountering sets constructed upon the empty set

Comment: In ZFC you need to code everything as a set.

Comment: Concrete books https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460690/recommendations-for-intermediate-level-logics-set-theory-books, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696462/logic-and-set-theory-books, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724805/recommended-books-articles-for-learning-set-theory,

Comment: ZFC doesn't try to model informal sets of objects found in the real world. Rather, it models a minimal collection of sets built up from the empty set which is sufficient to define the objects of mathematics ... e.g. natural numbers, functions, real numbers, etc.

Comment: In $\mathsf {ZFC}$  set theory the way to define a set as $B = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ where $\varphi(x)$ specifies a condition (like the "x is a painting of Picasso" above) does not work in general and we have to use [Specification axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification).

Comment: For a list of already existing objects $a,b,c$, we can use the definition: $B = \{ x \mid x=a \text { or } x=b \text { or } x=c \}$.

Comment: @Ned so the answer is no? In this case is there any other way to do "modeling" of these informal sets (like different theories)?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm sorry but the specification axiom, as you have just shown and stated, builds new sets using an existing set, $A$ for example. What I'm asking is, how can you construct an $A$ with something that isn't just a nesting of sets containig the empty set.

Comment: Exactly, but in $\mathsf {ZFC}$ there are no paintings nor painters.... Having said that, if you have already proved that the sets $a,b,c$ exist, then the above formula defines the set $\{ a,b,c \}$.

Comment: And similar, having proved thats et $\mathbb N$ exists, you can use Specification to prove that $\text {Even}= \{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \text { and } n \text { is Even} \}$.

Comment: Yes yes, now you answer me, what I wasn't asking though is "how can you construct $\{a,b,c\}$ knowing $a,b,c$ exist", I was asking "how you prove that certain $a,b,c$ exist".
So thanks for the answer.